# Loading subtitles in avplayer using ASBPlayerSubtitling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer, subtitle

I want to add subtitles to avplayer. I am following the readMe from https://github.com/autresphere/ASBPlayerSubtitling.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ASBPlayerScrubbing *scrubbing;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ASBPlayerSubtitling *subtitling;
```

//I have added 2 new objects in storyboard with which I have linked scrubbing and subtitling

```
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
[self.playerView.layer insertSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer atIndex:1];

self.scrubbing.player = _avPlayer;
NSURL *subtitlesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/astha/Downloads/OrangeIsTheNewBlack.srt"];
self.subtitling.player = self.avPlayer;
NSError *error = nil;
[self.subtitling loadSubtitlesAtURL:subtitlesURL error:&error];
NSLog(@"-Error: %@",error); //Error printed is nil
self.subtitling.containerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[self.playerView addSubview:self.subtitling.containerView];
```

The video plays just fine but I am unable to see the subtitles. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?